# OnPropertyChange does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, wpf

Cant seem to see where I am going wrong? the OnPropertyChange is not being recondnised any suggestions?

```
  public class MedicationList : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{



    public int MedicationID { get; set; }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return Description;
        }
        set
        { 
            OnPropertyChanged( "Description" );
            Description = value;

        }
    }
}
```

}

*EDIT*  I have added   `public class MedicationList : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Have you declared an `OnPropertyChanged` method anywhere in your `MedicationList` class? I don't see it.

Comment: Recursion detected: `Description = value;`

Comment: Your class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: Strictly speaking, it does not have to - it must just offer a method of the indicated name in some way.

Comment: @EDIT: And what happened? Did your problem go away?

Comment: Read and Study about basic concepts rather than jump to CODING.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface, which has single `PropertyChanged` event declared. You should raise this event if some of object's properties changed. Correct implementation:

```
public class MedicationList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _description; // storage for property value

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (_description == value) // check if value changed
                return; // do nothing if value same

            _description = value; // change value
            OnPropertyChanged("Description"); // pass changed property name
        }
    }

    // this method raises PropertyChanged event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) // if there is any subscribers 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the important part for the OP is that `OnPropertyChanged` does not magically appear out of thin air - not even when adding `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the list of implemented interfaces.

Comment: The name onPropertychange doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: @Mark actually it exists, at the bottom of class definition

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I know that, my default implementation was not pasted at first time

Comment: Genuis! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

I bet you want to do something like this:

```
public class MedicationList : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public int MedicationID { get; set; }
  private string m_Description;

  public string Description {
    get { return m_Description; }
    set {
      m_Description = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Description");
    }
  }

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
      throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

    var changed = PropertyChanged;
    if (changed != null) {
      changed(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Recursion detected here as well. :) Description = value

Answer (score 1):

You need the actual code the interface implements inside of your class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Public event for notifying the view when a property changes.
/// </summary>
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

/// <summary>
/// Raises the PropertyChanged event for the supplied property.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">The property name.</param>
internal void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method needs to be defined by your type to raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged::PropertyChanged` event

```
public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

...

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
  var saved = PropertyChanged;
  if (saved != null) { 
    var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
    saved(this, e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a base class and an interface.

With a base class, the members are automatically inherited and one needs to do nothing (except if some members need an `override`). With an interface, the class does not inherit the interface members automatically; you have to introduce them in your class. If you don't the compiler will complain.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherent BaseViewModel.

```
public class MedicationList : BaseViewModel
```