# WPF - change the selected Item of one combobox to the selected item of another combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have two combo boxes in my .xaml file. I would call the first combobox "main combo box ".  The other combobox also contains the same set of values as in the the first main combobox.

When I change the selection in the first combobox, I want the selection of the other combobox to be changed to the same value.

I have done it like in the following.

In my viewmodel, I have the following.

```
  private <MyClass> _firstComboBoxSelection;
  public <MyClass>  FirstComboboxSelection
  {
         set { _firstComboBoxSelection=value; }
         get { return _firstComboBoxSelection ; }

  }

   private <MyClass> _secondComboBoxSelection;
   public <MyClass>  SecondComboboxSelection
   {
         set { _secondComboBoxSelection=value; }
         get { return _secondComboBoxSelection ; }

    }
```

The comboboxes are like in the following.

```
       <ComboBox Name="cmbFirst"
                 SelectionChanged="cmbFirst_SelectionChanged"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding FirstComboboxSelection,Mode=TwoWay}"
                 ItemSource="{Binding MyData}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name" />

       <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SecondComboboxSelection,Mode=TwoWay}"
                 ItemSource="{Binding MyData}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

**MyData** is a ObservableCollection of **MyClass**. **MyClass** contains the property **Name**.
In my .xaml.cs file I have the following.

```
  private void cmbFirst_SelectionChanged(...)
  {

        _secondComboBoxSelection=_firstComboBoxSelection;
  }
```

But it does not change the second combo box as I want it to. Can someone help me to figure out where I have gone wrong ?

Comment: You don't need to do this in the code behind on an event.  You should be able to just bind the second combo box to the first combo box all in xaml.  You can bind to other controls properties in Xaml.

Comment: Can you pls give an example ? I'm new to WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you second combo box change

```
  <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SecondComboboxSelection}"
```

to

```
 <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding FirstComboboxSelection}"
```

You can also try to use SelectedValuePath like this

```
  <ComboBox Name="cmbFirst"
                 SelectionChanged="cmbFirst_SelectionChanged"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding FirstComboboxSelection,Mode=TwoWay}"
                 ItemSource="{Binding MyData}"
                 SelectedValuePath="Name" 
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

and in code you can do something like this -

```
  private <MyClass> _firstComboBoxSelection;
  public <MyClass>  FirstComboboxSelection
  {
         set { _firstComboBoxSelection=value;
                 OnPropertyChanged(_firstComboBoxSelection ); }
         get { return _firstComboBoxSelection ;
                }

  }
```

Comment: Can you pls tell me what is the namespace for OnPropertyChanged ? It says "OnPropertyChanged" does not exist in the current context

Comment: you should implement inotifyproperty changed interface which has single PropertyChanged event declared. You should raise this event if some of object's properties changed. See an example here                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885923/onpropertychange-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: Suppose I have a set of comboboxes from the second combobox. Only one combobox from cmbFirst. And set of comboboxes from cmbSecond. I only want one specific combobox  to change its selected item to the first combobox's selected item. How should I change the code then ?

Comment: Are you creating two combo boxes in one combo box?. If you want only one specific combo box to change its selected item then write the selection changed event for that specific combo box. If it still does not work please raise a separate question in stack overflow with what you have tried and also the code of your work because extended discussions in comments section is not allowed in stack overflow.